# Chrome not saving cookies with semicolon

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to save a cookie on my site using this function in javascript

```
setCookie: function(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```

Strangely this doesn't work in Chrome. It works in Firefox though.

If I change the semicolon to comma instead like below, it works in Chrome. But the attributes are set as part of the cookie value instead of attributes that the browser can read.

```
document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "," + expires + ",path=/";
```

Moreover, this only started happening last week. Has anyone else been noticing this? And if so, if there a solution for this?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

There seems to be an issue with the format of the date. I started using max-age instead with an integer value for seconds and it works fine now, even with the semi-colon.

Comment: What inputs are you using to store the cookie? Make sure the `cookie key` and the `cookie name` don't have semi-colons...

Comment: a test cookie looks like this, but it doesn't save: testcookie=testvalue;expires=Sat, 06 May 2017 16:02:37 GMT

Comment: In case it helps someone else some day: I needed to add the `Secure` attribute to get it working. The snippit I had copied didn't include that attribute, and it worked in Firefox but not Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are only certain fields that are predicated by a semicolon. As per MDN [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie):

> Any of the following cookie attribute values can optionally follow the key-value pair, specifying the cookie to set/update, and preceded by a semi-colon separator:

The attribute values are:

;path=path

;domain=domain

;max-age=max-age

;expires=date

;secure

The below code block works in Chrome Version 58.0.3029.96 (64-bit) for me.

```
var cname = "MyCookie";
var cvalue = "kjqwrQR1515jetrQT26jo2u5";
var expires = " ;expires=" + Date.now() + 100000;

document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + expires + " ;path=/";
```

If this format doesn't work for you, what values are your `cname` `cvalue`, and `exdays`?

Comment: Right. But exactly what I am doing. Or am I missing something?